# Perl array of hashes, keys return an error

Tags: perl

I have this code where array is an array of hashes:

```
my $hash = $array[0];
print "REF: " . ref($hash) . "\n";
my @names = keys ($hash);
```

The REF prints HASH so I know it is a hash.

But then the keys function returns an error:

Type of arg 1 to keys must be hash

How can I use the $hash as a hash?

Thanks!

Comment: The REF prints HASH so you know it is *a reference* to a hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$hash` isn't a hash, it's a hash reference. Therefore you need to dereference it before you can run keys on it.

Simplest way of doing this:

```
keys %$hash;
```

e.g.

```
foreach my $key ( keys %$hash ) {
    print $key, " => ", $hash -> {$key},"\n"; 
}
```

And yes, I am mixing two dereference methods deliberately. The `->` notation says 'dereference this' - it's commonly used for object oriented stuff.

For more complex dereferencing `%$hash{'key'}` is ambiguous, so you start needing brackets - `%{$hash{'key'}}` for example.

See:

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html